# Как в StackPane можно достать номер эелемента на который навелась мышь JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Как в StackPane можно достать номер эелемента на который навелась мышь ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто. Вам надо добавить обработчик события "перемещение мышью над компонентом", или onMouseMoved. В обработчике получайте доступ к коллекции элементов, находящихся в StackPane, а у коллекции вызовите метод indexOf. Вот пример:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        ArrayList<Pos> pos = new ArrayList<>();
        pos.add(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        pos.add(Pos.CENTER);
        pos.add(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
            Button btn = new Button(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            btn.setOnMouseMoved(this::mouseDrag);
            StackPane.setAlignment(btn, pos.get(i));
            stackPane.getChildren().add(btn);
        }
    }

    public void mouseDrag(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        Button btn = (Button)mouseEvent.getSource();
        int index = stackPane.getChildren().indexOf(btn);
        System.out.println("Index of the element under the mouse: " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!
А есть ли способ достать уровень объекта на которой навелась мышь ?
А то после того как я делаю toFront() хотелось бы вернуть его назад (но не в самый конец (toBack()) ,а в прежнее место)

Comment: @RedCape если Вам помог ответ - отметьте его правильным, чтобы другие участники могли этим воспользоваться. А для следующего Вашего вопроса лучше оформите новый вопрос :)

Comment: Я делал вопрос)
Но на него что то не отвечают (

Comment: @RedCape я написал Вам в той теме, посмотрите, может быть это поможет.

Comment: Привет, можешь посмотреть последнею тему, вроде все правильно написал, но что то не работает