# Как вернуть объект на изначальный уровень в StackPane

Tags: java, javafx

В javaFX есть функция toFront() которая двигает объект вперед, а есть ли функция возвращающая назад(toBack не подойдет потому что она двигает в самый конец)

Comment: Вот список методов: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html. Смотрите там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного исследовал Вашу проблему, и кое - какие успехи есть. Изучив документацию на досуге, метода, отвечающего за возвращение на обратную позицию я не обнаружил. В связи с этим бна скорую руку были придуманы два метода, которые выполняют Вашу задачу:

1. Запоминание позиции и при возвращении сдвиг всех элементов, стоящих ранее *за* текущий элемент.
2. Запоминание позиции и удаление со вставкой из коллекции элементов, находящихся в панели.

Первый метод я не стал реализовывать, он не очень красив, и, по - идее при использовании такого количества вызовов *toFront()* будет хромать оптимизация(если у Вас множество элементов в коллекции). А вот второй метод был реализован. Он простой, и по идее, не слишком сильно будет нагружать систему, так как коллекция элементов в *StackPane* - это *ObservableList*, основанный на листе. Вставка будет осуществляться достаточно быстро(могу ошибаться). Код похож на листинг из [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947760/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-stackpane-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C-javafx/948175?noredirect=1#comment1579507_948175) поста. Приятного использования:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        for(int i = 5;i>0;i--){
            int pow = i  * 10;
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j = 0;j<pow;j++){
                res.append(i);
            }
            Button btn = new Button(res.toString());
            btn.setOnMouseMoved(this::mouseDrag);
            btn.setOnMouseClicked(this::mouseClick);
            stackPane.getChildren().add(btn);
        }
    }

    public void mouseDrag(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        Button btn = (Button)mouseEvent.getSource();
        int index = stackPane.getChildren().indexOf(btn);
        System.out.println("Index of the element under the mouse: " + index);
    }

    public void mouseClick(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
        Button btn = (Button)mouseEvent.getSource();
        int index = -1;
        if(btn.getUserData() == null) {
            index = stackPane.getChildren().indexOf(btn);
            btn.setUserData(index);
            btn.toFront();
            System.out.println("Btn to front");
        } else {
            index = (int)btn.getUserData();
            stackPane.getChildren().remove(btn);
            stackPane.getChildren().add(index, btn);
            btn.setUserData(null);
            System.out.println("Btn to back position");
        }
    }
}
```

Код протестирован, при нажатии на кнопку она отправляется на самый верх z - последовательности, при повторном нажатии - на свое обратное место.